# Python 2 and pyenv: build with shared libraries on macOS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pyenv, macos-monterey

I'm trying to install Python 2 with pyenv and shared libraries on macOS 12.3.1 with the command:

```
export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" && pyenv install 2.7.18
```

But I get the error:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Installing Python-2.7.18...
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
patching file setup.py
patching file Mac/Tools/pythonw.c
patching file setup.py
patching file Doc/library/ctypes.rst
patching file Lib/test/test_str.py
patching file Lib/test/test_unicode.py
patching file Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c
patching file Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c
patching file Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h
patching file Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c
patching file setup.py
patching file Mac/Modules/qt/setup.py
patching file setup.py
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.3.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/6f/08_5byqn69q2bpqx5x7vs1000000gn/T/python-build.20220418170004.43219
Results logged to /var/folders/6f/08_5byqn69q2bpqx5x7vs1000000gn/T/python-build.20220418170004.43219.log

Last 10 log lines:
        echo "generate-posix-vars failed" ; \
        rm -f ./pybuilddir.txt ; \
        exit 1 ; \
    fi
dyld[51418]: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/6f/08_5byqn69q2bpqx5x7vs1000000gn/T/python-build.20220418170004.43219/Python-2.7.18/python.exe
  Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (no such file)
/bin/sh: line 1: 51418 Abort trap: 6           DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/folders/6f/08_5byqn69q2bpqx5x7vs1000000gn/T/python-build.20220418170004.43219/Python-2.7.18 ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
generate-posix-vars failed
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

It seems that is trying to reference the system's Python 2 which doesn't exist anymore.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't your system's python 2 exist anymore? That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Python has been removed officially by Apple on macOS 12.3.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you had removed it, which would have been a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it fixed:

1. Re-install command line tools:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

2. Run macOS updates to update the command line tools.
3. Restart the computer. (Not sure if this had anything to do with it, but it didn't hurt).
4. Install Python 2 with pyenv:

```
export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" && pyenv install 2.7.18
```

Comment: Nice, that worked for me! Didn't need the --enabled-shared option.